# mysql using subquery with no join

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

here are the relevant tables

```
movie(id, title, relYear, category, runTime, director,
studioName, description, rating)

actor(aID, fName, surname, gender)

stars(movieID, actorID)

movGenre(movieID, genre)
```

I'm just trying to return movies where 'Michael Fassbender' stars using a subquery ... 'id' in movie refers to the the movie id **not** the actor id if that was the case I could do

```
SELECT title, category
FROM movie 
WHERE 'id' =(SELECT 'aID'
             FROM actor
             WHERE fName='Michael' and surname='Fassbender')
```

Is there a way to do it without using any joins?

Comment: Yes, there are some way to do it without `JOIN`s but why? There are even ways to do it without MySQL, but why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can utilize [Correlated Subquery](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/correlated-subqueries.html) with [`Exists()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html)

```
SELECT m.title, m.category
FROM movie AS m
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM stars AS s 
              JOIN actor AS a ON a.aID = s.actorID
              WHERE a.fName = 'Michael' AND 
                    a.surname = 'Fassbender' AND
                    s.movieID = m.id)
```

---

Above solution still utilize `JOIN` in some way (inside the subquery). A solution utilizing no Join at all can be:

```
SELECT title, category
FROM movie
WHERE id IN (SELECT movieID 
             FROM stars 
             WHERE actorID IN (SELECT aID 
                               FROM actor 
                               WHERE fName = 'Michael' AND 
                                     surname = 'Fassbender'))
```

**P.S.** Unless this is some trick assignment/HW, I would seriously recommend against using this query in a real-life application.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT m.title, m.category
FROM movie 
INNER JOIN stars s
ON s.movieID = m.id
INNER JOIN actors a
ON s.actorID = a.aID
   AND a.fName='Michael' 
   AND a.surname='Fassbender'
```

Comment: OP asking for solution without joins :-)  "Is there a way to do it without using any joins?"

Comment: :-) @MadhurBhaiya Do you really believe that your solution has no `JOIN`s? do Ctrl+F ;-) You will be surprised. :-)